# Getting an error going from Dataframe to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, dataframe, databricks

I'm looking at the documentation here.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

I keep getting this error.

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_sql'
```

Below, is all my code.  I don't see what's wrong here.  What is going on?

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib
import pyodbc

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=server_name.database.windows.net;DATABASE=my_db;UID=my_id;PWD=my_pw")
myeng = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
                           

df.to_sql(name="dbo.my_table", con=myeng, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the object wasn't an actual dataframe that Pandas could interpret.  This fixed the problem.

```
# convert pyspark.sql DF to Pandas DF
df = df.toPandas()
```